# How to get image from assets folder in windows phone 8.1 and assign it to a model's property

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have a model with property as BitmapImage and I am trying to load and image from root -> Assets -> Icons folder and set it to this property . But always gives me the error "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."
We originally created this project in WP8.0 and then targeted it to 8.1

```
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"../Assets/Icons/noprofilepic.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
                BuddyImage = bi;
```

Property is defined as :

```
    private BitmapImage _BuddyImage;
    public BitmapImage BuddyImage
    {
        get { return _BuddyImage; }
        set { _BuddyImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged("BuddyImage"); }
    }
```

xaml control looks like below

```
   <Image Source="{Binding BuddyImage}" Width="75" Height="75" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use ms-appx:/// for example:

```
  bi.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/noprofilepic.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

objBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.scale-240.png");

This will work. First Check whether you are able to display images without binding.If not check the build action property of the particular image is set as "Content".

Comment: yes , it gives invalid uri error. Strangely the other place if I use any one the above solutions you gave it works..not sure why I am not able to do this in viewmodel class

Comment: public BitmapImage BuddyImage
    {
        get
        {
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/noprofilepic.png");
            return bi;
        }
    }

Comment: Add this in your view model

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the following worked fine for me:

```
new Uri("Assets/Icons/noprofilepic.png", UriKind.Relative)
```